# Manipulating xsl attributes before XSLT

Tags: html, xslt

Given xsl file to change color

```
 <xsl:if test="!colorChanges()">
    <StaticLabel style="{StaticLabel/@style}">                                                                                                      
      <Caption>
    <xsl:value-of select="$StaticLabel/Caption"/>                               
      </Caption>                                                          
      <PreviewCaption>
         <xsl:value-of select="$StaticLabel/Caption"/>
       </PreviewCaption>                                                                                                                  
     </StaticLabel>
  </xsl:if>
```

Given this xml data

```
 <StaticLabel style="font-family:Arial;color:#000000;font-size:9pt">
    <Caption><![CDATA[FoodType]]></Caption>
    <Name><![CDATA[French]]></Name>
 </StaticLabel>
</xsl:if>
```

**Current result after xslt**

```
<StaticLabel style="font-family:Arial;color:#000000;font-size:9pt">                                                  
   <Caption>Food Type</Caption>                                                 
   <PreviewCaption>French</PreviewCaption>                                              
</StaticLabel>
```

Is there anyway to *ONLY* change the color while keeping other style attributes before xslt is performed without updating the xml file?

**Expected result:**

```
<StaticLabel style="font-family:Arial;color:#CCCCCC;font-size:9pt">                                                  
   <Caption>Food Type</Caption>                                                 
   <PreviewCaption>French</PreviewCaption>                                              
</StaticLabel>
```

**Possible XSL solution**

```
<xsl:if test="colorChanges()">
    <StaticLabel>       
      <xsl:attribute name="style">                                                        
        //other style attributes stay same and ONLY edit color 
    <xsl:text>color:#CCCCCC"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>                                                                                              
      <Caption>
    <xsl:value-of select="$StaticLabel/Caption"/>                               
      </Caption>                                                          
      <PreviewCaption>
         <xsl:value-of select="$StaticLabel/Caption"/>
       </PreviewCaption>                                                                                                                  
     </StaticLabel>
  </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Is this XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution:**

**This *generic* transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pStyle" select="'font-size:12pt'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vStyleName"
      select="concat(';',substring-before($pStyle, ':'),':')"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vCurrentStyleValue" select=
 "substring-before(substring-after(concat(';', /*/@style, ';'), $vStyleName),
                   ';')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vCurrentStyle"
       select="concat($vStyleName,$vCurrentStyleValue)"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identiy">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/@style">
  <xsl:attribute name="style">
   <xsl:variable name="vprecStyles" select=
   "substring-before(concat(';',., $vCurrentStyle), $vCurrentStyle)"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="substring($vprecStyles, 2)"/>
   <xsl:if test="$vprecStyles">;</xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select="$pStyle"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(concat(';',.), $vCurrentStyle)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<StaticLabel style="font-family:Arial;color:#000000;font-size:9pt">
   <Caption>Food Type</Caption>
   <PreviewCaption>French</PreviewCaption>
</StaticLabel>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<StaticLabel style="font-family:Arial;color:#CCCCCC;font-size:9pt">
   <Caption>Food Type</Caption>
   <PreviewCaption>French</PreviewCaption>
</StaticLabel>
```

**When we change the `$pStyle` parameter to**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pStyle" select="'font-family:Courier'"/>
```

**then again the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<StaticLabel style="font-family:Courier;color:#000000;font-size:9pt">
   <Caption>Food Type</Caption>
   <PreviewCaption>French</PreviewCaption>
</StaticLabel>
```

**If we change the `$pStyle` parameter to**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pStyle" select="'font-size:12pt'"/>
```

**We again get the correct result**:

```
<StaticLabel style="font-family:Arial;color:#000000;font-size:12pt">
   <Caption>Food Type</Caption>
   <PreviewCaption>French</PreviewCaption>
</StaticLabel>
```

**Finally, if we change the `$pStyle` parameter to:**

```
 <xsl:param name="pStyle" select="'line-height:15pt'"/>
```

**we again get the correct, desired result**:

```
<StaticLabel style="font-family:Arial;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;line-height:15pt">
   <Caption>Food Type</Caption>
   <PreviewCaption>French</PreviewCaption>
</StaticLabel>
```

**This is quite error-proof -- observe**:

```
<StaticLabel style="font-family:Arial;background-color:#ffffff;color:#000000;font-size:9pt">
   <Caption>Food Type</Caption>
   <PreviewCaption>French</PreviewCaption>
</StaticLabel>
```

**and we have the `$pStyle` parameter again as:**

```
 <xsl:param name="pStyle" select="'color:#CCCCCC'"/>
```

**We still get the correct result (not confused by other CSS properties ending with "color"):**

```
<StaticLabel style="font-family:Arial;background-color:#ffffff;color:#CCCCCC;font-size:9pt">
   <Caption>Food Type</Caption>
   <PreviewCaption>French</PreviewCaption>
</StaticLabel>
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution -- much easier**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pStyle" select="'color:#CCCCCC'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vStyleName" select=
                  "substring-before($pStyle, ':')"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vcurStyles"
      select="tokenize(/*/@style, ';')"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vnewStyles" select=
  "if($vcurStyles[substring-before(.,':') eq $vStyleName])
     then ($vcurStyles[substring-before(.,':') ne $vStyleName],
           $pStyle)
     else ($vcurStyles, $pStyle)
  "/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identiy">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/@style">
  <xsl:attribute name="style" select="string-join($vnewStyles, ';')">
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: for the XSL 2.0 solution, creating the vnewStyles variable throws an unexpected XPath expression

Comment: and how do i use the template you created for XSL 2.0 with the current XSL file (first code snippet above) i have ?

Comment: @bouncingHippo, This isn't a "template" -- it is a complete transformation (stylesheet). Just apply it to the XML cocument. I assume that you have an XSLT 2.0 processor available -- they typically have a command-line utility that applies a transformation (residing in its file) to an XML document -- also residing in its own file. For example, for Saxon 9.x, use this command line: java.exe -Xms512M -Xmx512M  -jar yourDir\saxon9.jar   -t  -repeat:1 -o %out%  %xml%  %xsl%  [param1=value1 param2=value2 ...]  -- where %out% , %xml% and %xsl% are the files for output, xml doc and xslt stylesheet.

Comment: @bouncingHippo, As for exceptions being thrown, do verify that you are really using an XSLT 2.0 processor. I always test my solutions before publishing them -- I actually copy and paste the result from the actual execution of the transformation -- as this was done for this answer.

Comment: thanks i really appreciate your attention to details, and reproducing it on your end. i did some tinkering and finally got it to work